# How to do conditional compile based on target names?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using testflightapp.com SDK in my project to track crashes during beta test which is conducted on testflightapp.com. I have 2 targets in my Xcode project, which are "ad-hoc" and "app store".

To initiate testflight SDK, I need to put down a line of code in the AppDelegate.m like:

```
[TestFlight takeOff:@"67bebb8d8e5396a...A4LjQwNjQ4NA"];
```

Now, I want the compiler to exclude this line of code when I compile for the target "app store", because it doesn't make sense to trigger testflight SDK when it goes to public.

I'm expecting something like #ifdef, but I couldn't get a clue by searching the forum.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a [user-defined build setting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Build_Settings.html) that you set in the build settings for each target, and then use an `#if` or `#ifdef` directive to test that setting. For example, select your 'ad-hoc' target, click on 'Build Settings', and scroll down to the 'User-Defined' section. Then just click the 'Add Build Setting' button and choose 'Add User-Defined Setting'. You can set different values for your setting for each build configuration (debug, release, etc.).

[image: Picture of relevant Xcode settings]

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick answer. I couldn't find the "user-defined setting" you mentioned, however, I found "Preprocessor Marcros" (there's a DEBUG=1 defined for debug, so I defined a TESTFLIGHT=1) can meet my need. THANK YOU!

Comment: Added an image to illustrate user-defined build settings.

Comment: yeah, I'm dame stupid, I tried searching with "user" which turned out nothing. okay, it's a section, thanks

Comment: I didn't see the section either in XCode 4.6.3, but as this answer points out there is  an "Add Build Setting" button at the bottom right which allows you to add a user-defined setting. If you do this you will see the User-Defined section appear with your new custom setting

Answer (score 6):

It is a old post but would like to share another way to achieve this.

The solution is like create few (depends on how much targets you have) files with same class/function/variable but added to different targets.

Like for me, I have main target and UITest target so I have following two files

`BuildConfiguration_main.swift` added to main target.

```
struct BuildConfiguration {
    static let isMainTarget = true
    static let isUITestTarget = false
}
```

`BuildConfiguration_UITest.swift` added to UITest target.

```
struct BuildConfiguration {
    static let isMainTarget = false
    static let isUITestTarget = true
}
```

Then in you code, you can use `BuildConfiguration.isMainTarget` or `BuildConfiguration.isUITestTarget` to tell where is target the code is running if you share some codes between two targets.

Comment: This is so much better than littering the project file with ugly build settings. Thanks!

Comment: This is a fine technique, but it's not the conditional compilation that the OP asked for. Conditional compilation means that the compiler decides what piece code to compile based on environment settings. Using the method presented here, the compiler compiles all the code; it may strip out the unwanted code as an optimization, but that's different from never compiling it at all.